# How do I replicate a Cinnamon window manager configuration?

Tags: automation, window-managers

I have a master Linux computer with several Cinnamon window manager options set.

How can I replicate this setting to a new machine?

Comment: @anx, Can you expand this into an answer with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the original box:

```
dconf dump /org/cinnamon/ >/tmp/cinnamon-$USER.dconf
scp /tmp/cinnamon-$USER.dconf newbox:/tmp
```

On the new box:

```
dconf reset -f /org/cinnamon/
dconf load -f /org/cinnamon/ </tmp/cinnamon-$USER.dconf
```

Ignore warnings about unwritable keys.

The [dconf doc](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/wiki/Backing-up-and-restoring-your-cinnamon-settings-(dconf)) notes that this can crash cinnamon and recommends you restart cinnamon following this step.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize your dconf-based settings to a text format and just copy that over. If you are just interested in specific users, restore to the destination users home:

```
# create a human-readable text file with your settings
ssh user@source dconf dump > cinnamon.dconf

# review and delete sections not applicable/appropriate on the other machine(s)
vim cinnamon.dconf

# load the settings on the destination machine
ssh user@destination dconf load < cinnamon.dconf
```

(but if you need it system-wide, these dumps can be configured in `/etc/dconf` as system-wide defaults)

Note that the dump contains only settings explicitly defined in that users dconf store, meaning if you copy over to a different version (with different defaults) and have never touched a specific setting, the result may still be different on the target.

Caveat: This will not copy some non-dconf settings that you may also be interested in, e.g. it will only copy the path of the desktop background - not the image file itself.